# Simple way to execute MySQL query statement Asynchorously in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, asynchronous

I'm creating a game modification that uses MySQL to get and store player data. It refreshes it's client data from the database every 4 seconds, but because it is blocking, it freezes about a second as it gets the data.

Is there any simple way to execute the command async?

Comment: Database queries do not take a long time (10s of milliseconds)  Maybe you  should reevaluate how and how often you actually do database access. Maybe caching could work ?

Comment: Hmm, I think I see my error then. I have objects for all kinds of things like private messages, status updates, etc. When each object is created, it executes a query.

Comment: Use an extra Thread that every 4 seconds wake up(Thread.sleep(4000)) and do the database query,really nice tutorials here http://tutorials.jenkov.com ,also set the autoCommit(false) and do commit often.

Comment: Yes, but I believe threads can't modify variables of the Main thread/thread other then it's own.

Comment: They can.Set the variable public ,volatile , if you need static and using synchronized keyword.Check some tutorials and the magic happens.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html  not easy but learning them will make your app a lot faster.

Comment: @NicholasHarris I would really step back, and take a look at your basic design before going down a synchronized thread path, that is complex and error prone. Sometimes stepping away from the keyboard and arming yourself with paper and pencil is a good way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(() -> {
       //Your jdbc call here
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Here, we can safely update the GUI
            // because we'll be called from the
            // event dispatch thread
            MW.append(foo);
        }
    });
    });
```

Comment: But can threads like this modify variables in the main thread?

Comment: @NicholasHarris, i have updated my answer please check it and upvote and mark as answer if it helps you

Comment: I'll try this, and mark as answer if it works. Thank you!

Comment: I'll mark it as an answer, though I'm getting some weird bugs and still slight lagspikes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not doing so already, use Threads. Override the run() method for things you want to run asynchronously in Java.

Also just making sure, you wait until the server returns the database data before performing another request right?

Comment: I can't use threads because they can't modify variables in the main thread.